# Deleting a has_many_attached Item in Active Storage Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to create a delete method to delete an image that relates to an event in Rails. I've actually gotten it to work before sending on the code but my problem now is making the action happen with Ajax. The below code works and refreshes my form page with the updated images list.

Event.rb

```
has_many_attached :images
```

Admin_events_controller

```
def destroy_single_image
  @event_image = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find_by(blob_id)
  @event_image.purge
  redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
end
```

View

```
<% if @event.images.any? %>
  <% @event.images.each do |event_image| %>
    <%= image_tag event_image, height: "100" %>
       <%= link_to 'Remove', destroy_single_image_admin_events_path(id: event_image.id),
            method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

routes

```
resources :events do
  collection do
    get 'destroy_multiple_images'
    # get 'destroy_single_image'
    post 'destroy_single_image', action: "destroy_single_image"
  end
end
```

Request Paramaters (Old request parameters which led me to change my action in the routes file. Am I correct in doing this? It works now as above but i'm afraid of any security issues)

```
{"_method"=>"delete", "authenticity_token"=>"CrL7UAG671aSMiIVL6slvukHWT5S1YEaSEEdgtu1m8PKGm0deZk15uoPhXzhq/1oLNVp5otd8ai55tM0sLNGpw==", "controller"=>"admin/events", "action"=>"destroy", "id"=>"destroy_single_image", "format"=>"769"}
```

So my issue is now with respond_to :js in the destroy_single_image method. If I add this like below.

Admin_events_controller

```
def destroy_single_image
  @event_image = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:id])
  @event_image.purge

  respond_to :js
  #redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
end
```

I know receive an error in my server logs.

[image]

[image]

This i'm guessing has to do with the routes action call? I've not added the js file but it's in the same folder as the events controller and called the same as the method destory_single_image.js.erb

Anybody able to shed some light on this please? Thank you.

So to recap. The above code works normally but refreshed the edit form page as the server is called. I'm now getting errors when trying to make the call remote: true and have the respond_to :js in my controller. :D